# Why can't Heroku find my autoload.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, git, heroku, composer-php

I'm setting up a demo site for a Wordpress plugin on Heroku. My plugin uses composer to manage dependencies, and it's configured as a git submodule on my local installation. I push to heroku and everything seems to work. I use `heroku run bash` to ssh into the app and manually run `composer install` from inside my plugin. Then I log into the site and try to activate my plugin... but I get the following error:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.

Warning: require_once(/app/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/wp-github-pipeline.php on line 23 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/app/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php') in /app/wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/wp-github-pipeline.php on line 23
```

I don't get it.  With `heroku run bash` I can see that the file is actually there. And I don't get this issue locally or on another remote server. Why is it happening here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check if `composer install` creates the vendor directory and autoload.php?

Comment: Yes it does. It's not there immediately after `git push heroku...` but then I do `heroku run bash` to run `composer install` manually and then it's there. But the error remains. That's what's so strange/frustrating about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure *why* this worked but it appears that Heroku doesn't really play nicely with composer.json somewhere other than the project root. So I took my project's composer.json and moved it to the project root, then I added...

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "wp-content/plugins/wp-github-pipeline/vendor"
}
```

...which caused the dependancies I needed (and the autoload.php) to get installed in the original location.

With this, I am able to push to Heroku normally without issues.

I have NO idea why I was able to run `composer install` manually without it working. I also have NO idea why `heroku run bash` would show me files that aren't actually there.

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have to regenerate the autoload. Hope that you have written code within composer.json for autoloads.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

This will regenerate your autoload and it will solve your problem. If not please modify your question by pasting your composer.json.

Comment: are you running composer update on heroku and changing/adding any files after running composer udpate??

Comment: Yes on Heroku. Not changing files after.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this was add an `include_path` to my `.user.ini` file. That ini file needs to be located in the **document root**, not the app's root.

> include_path = ".:/app/.heroku/php/lib/php:/app/vendor/"

Don't copy my `include_path` example verbatim, as it might now be the needed include path for your app. Get your current include path from Heroku's error log, and then append `:/app/vendor` to it.

What's important there is adding `/app/vendor/` to the include_path. That will point your`require` php statement to the spot where Heroku puts the `autoload.php`.